# Calling Matlab from C++ with Refreshed Inputs

Tags: c++, qt, matlab, mex, matlab-cvst

I am working on a Qt Project that requires me to to work with Matlab c++ shared library. I am basically working with Images that I acquire, and I need to do further processing on them later.

It is absolutely necessary for me that I acquire Images in C Platform, and then call Matlab for processing whenever needed. My Images are coming at a high speed : some 100 frames per sec.

The problem is that whenever I am calling Matlab in a loop, I am able to process the acquired images, but not real time. It takes one or two seconds between the subsequent calls in Matlab. I am assuming it is flushing off the other images and just plotting some images.

Can you suggest me a way so that I can just call Matlab function once, and my inputs be changed in real time. I dont intend to use Matlab Engine because that would require me to have Matlab Installed in every computer, my project runs on.

Comment: Do you mean that you build a shared library from the matlab code using the matlab to C interface. And call that shared library to process your image?

Comment: @Min Lin..Yes, this is exactly what my project is all about. The Images are coming to me at a speed of 100 frames per seconds, and I need to be able to do some parametrization using SDK in Qt and all the processing using the built matlab library.

Comment: I don't quite understand this "I can just call Matlab function once, and my inputs be changed everytime." Is your question how to make it real time at 100 frames per sec?

Comment: @Min Lin .. Yes Please. Precisely what I want my program to do.

Comment: But if your processing code need to take 1 second to finish one image, it is almost impossible unless you have 100 parallel processors and distribute the work.

Comment: I had previously saved all my images as mat files and tried implementing my processing code, it worked smooth and i could get around 100 frames per second. I think its the fact that I am calling the matlab library function all the time from my loop that is takes so much time? Is it?
I also wanted to ask, if Pipes will do the trick for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26849/discussion-between-min-lin-and-alok)

Comment: If pipes are used, I think the overhead will only be stronger. Because the data is then transfered between processes.
You may be doubting that loading the mex takes time, however, if your mex is statically linked in your project, it will only be loaded at the time the program starts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a library from MATLAB code using MATLAB Compiler, and expecting to be able to call it 100 times per second?

That's not going to happen - the overhead of calling the library is too high. It sounds like your library might also be doing some plotting, which is likely to take too long as well.

You could perhaps look into using MATLAB Coder to convert your MATLAB image processing algorithm to C code, and then integrate the C code directly into your main code. Much of Image Processing Toolbox is supported by MATLAB Coder, as is Computer Vision System Toolbox and much of the Signal Processing-related toolboxes.

Comment: I agree @Sam Roberts. I am not getting it at 100 frames per seconds. But I realised that loading a data takes a longer time. Also Calling Plot functions are time consuming as well. I worked on the code, pass data by reference, load data minimal number of times, and call plot function when and where necessary, I could get it fast enough to look like a real time video. Initially one of my data was getting loaded everytime from a mat file. That took a lot of time.
And Yes, I am going to replace the library sooner or later with c++ maths/computer vision/graphics library.
Thank you for your input.